# white theme not showing the text

Tags: android, themes

I am currently making an app (Android 1.6) that can change between two different themes.
I made a custom theme that takes the Android light theme as a parent!
The trouble is that when I switch to white theme my text is not drawn but if I select something I can see the text.  Furthermore when I switch themes my titleText, previous and next are the same as in my dark theme.

Here is the code I use for the theme:

```
<style name="Theme.White" parent="android:Theme.Light"> 
        <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/text_color_dark</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/text_color_dark</item>
        <item name="textPrev">@style/text_prev</item>
        <item name="textRegular">@style/text_regular</item>
        <item name="textTitle">@style/text_title</item>
        <item name="textNext">@style/text_next</item>
        <item name="pageBack">@style/page_back</item>
        <item name="whiteBack">@style/white_back</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimaryInverse">@android:color/primary_text_light</item>

    </style>

</resources>
```

This is my style:

```
<style name="text_prev">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/text_color</item>
</style>

<style name="text_next">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/default_text_color_2</item>
</style>

<style name="text_regular">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/text_color_dark</item>
</style>

<style name="text_title">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/text_color_dark</item>
</style>

<style name="page_back">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/white_background</item>

</style>
<style name="white_back">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/white_container</item>
    <item name="android:padding">10sp</item>
</style>
```

I use two more resources that are in my res/drawable folder. Everything works fine in the standard theme, but as soon as I switch to my light theme my text disappears.
Is there something that I'm doing wrong?

Comment: ok i have done something that works ONLY partially.  
in my main.xml in stead of writing android:textColor/@color/...
i write style="?normalText"

and i declare a style normalText_default and a normalText_white in stlyes.
then i add a theme item normalText in both themes.

This works only in my white theme that now sets a black textColor, but my default theme doesnt do anything with the value i gave to the text. it just sets everything to a grayish/offwhite colour!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code snippet above you're setting both background and text to the same color i.e. "color/text_color_dark", these should be different.

```
    <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/text_color_dark</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/text_color_dark</item>
```